# Does rust 0.10 have a rl package?

Tags: readline, rust

I'm starting to use rust to create a little toy command prompt applicationusing the gnu readline library. I started using the c foreign function interface but then [came across this in rust 0.8](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v0.8/doc/extra/rl/index.html).

The crate extra has a module `extra::rl` which appears to be a readline with all the tools that are needed. My question is, is this present in rust 0.10 and if so where is it? if not, is it packaged as an external module, and if so where can I find it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use std::c_str;

#[link(name = "readline")]
extern {
    fn readline (p: *std::libc::c_char) -> * std::libc::c_char;
}

fn rust_readline (prompt: &str) -> Option<~str> {
    let cprmt = prompt.to_c_str();
    cprmt.with_ref(|c_buf| {
    unsafe {
        let ret = c_str::CString::new (readline (c_buf), true);
        ret.as_str().map(|ret| ret.to_owned())
    }
    })
}

fn eval(input: &str)
{
    println! ("{}", input);
}

fn main()
{
    loop {
        let val = rust_readline (">>> ");
        match val {
            None => { break }
            _ => {
                let input = val.unwrap ();
                eval(input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample REPL style interpreter that just prints instead of eval'ing. Based on code from http://redbrain.co.uk/2013/11/09/rust-and-readline-c-ffi/. His example no longer compiles.

This code is now on github [here](http://github.com/shaleh/rust-readline).

Comment: Thanks Sean, I feel like an idiot for not having answered my own question when I got a decent working example (it includes history). It's pretty rough and ready there may very well be bugs in there (I co-opted one of my functions to just return zero when it shouldn't, I can't remember why reading it now) but it compiles and works. I appreciate you having a look at this for me. Can I take that to mean that as far as you know there is no longer a readline package in the standard library? thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I really should have said, I came up with an answer to my own question, it includes a history for readline. I have put it here in case anyone else wants some of this functionality.

```
//! Readline FFI

//extern crate libc;
use std::libc;
use libc::c_char;
use std::c_str;

#[link(name = "readline")]

extern {
    fn readline(p: *c_char) -> * c_char;
    fn add_history(l: *c_char);
}

pub fn rust_readline(prompt: &str) -> Option<~str> {
    let c_prompt = prompt.to_c_str();
    c_prompt.with_ref(|c_buf| {
        unsafe {
            let ret = c_str::CString::new(readline(c_buf), true);
            ret.as_str().map(|ret| ret.to_owned())
        }
    })
}

pub fn rust_add_history(line: &str) -> int {
    // if line.len() == 0 { return Err("Empty string!") }
    let c_line = line.to_c_str();
    c_line.with_ref(|my_c_line| {
        unsafe {
            // println!("{}", my_c_line)
            add_history(my_c_line);
        }
    });
    0
    }

fn main() {
    loop {
        let val = rust_readline("mikes_lisp> ");
        match val {
            None    => { break }
            _       => {
                let input = val.unwrap();
                rust_add_history(input);
                println!("you said: '{}'", input);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and popped our code up on github. https://github.com/shaleh/rust-readline. I added a check in readline() to ensure a NULL response does not fail just return None. I also twiddled your add_history a bit. Thanks for the push. Comments there are welcomed.

Comment: @SeanPerry Nice, and it looks good. I'd edit your answer to include the github link so future people can see it more easily.